# React Hook "useEffect" is called in function "shoes" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm getting the following error:

**React Hook "useEffect" is called in function "shoes" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks**

I'm not sure exactly what is the error in my code:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import "../App.css"

function shoes() {
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchItems();
    }, []);

    const fetchItems = async () => {
        const data = await fetch('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
        console.log(data)
    };

    return ( < h1 className = "main" > Shoes < /h1> );
    }
}

export default shoes;
```

Comment: Try with a capital S

Comment: WOW! That fixed the issue! "Shoes". So in conclusion all components must start with a capital letter? Thank you for the help!

Comment: Also, both ways work:
function Shoes()
and
const Shoes = () =>{ 
just needs the capital letter in the beginning

Comment: yes, they did this in order to have clear distinction between `<div>`, `<a>` etc. and React components

Answer (score 57, accepted):

As described [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized), React component names need to start with **a capital letter**.
That's because React treats components starting with a lowercase letter as DOM tags.

Therefore you should name it `Shoes`.

Answer (score 2):

I would also like to add the solution that worked for me. This was supposed to be a component so capitalizing the first letter worked, but if you're trying to create a hook and the above error occurs then append `use` at the start of your hook. For example `useShoes()`